# aChartEngine: getting coordinates of tallest bar in the graph(Bar chart)

Tags: android, graph, achartengine

We are using AChart engine to draw bar graph. As per design requirement have to place an image on top of  the tallest bar in the graph. We know the index of largest value in the XY series.  Is there any method to find the coordinates of the tallest bar to position the image? Below is the helper class we are using to generate the bar graph. When user taps on the bar we have to place an image on top of the bar.

Issues :

Not able to get the click event correctly
How to position the image on top of the bar

```
public class BarGraphHelper {

private Context mContext;
private BarGraph mBarGraph;
private DisplayMetrics mMetrics;
private XYMultipleSeriesDataset mDataset;
private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer;
private View barChartView = null;
private BarChart chart;

public BarGraphHelper(Context context, BarGraph barGraph){
    mContext = context;
    mBarGraph = barGraph;
    init();
}


private void init() {
    renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    mDataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    mMetrics = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
}


public View getBarGraphView(){

    if(renderer == null){
        return null;
    }

    getBarGraphDataset();
    renderer = getBarRenderer();
    setBarGraphSettings();
    chart = new BarChart(mDataset, renderer, Type.DEFAULT);
    barChartView = new GraphicalView(mContext, chart);
    barChartView.setOnClickListener(onBarClick);
    return barChartView;
}




 private void setBarGraphSettings() {
       if(renderer != null){

        renderer.setXAxisMin(0.5);
        renderer.setYAxisMin(0);
        renderer.setYAxisMax(110);
        renderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.WHITE);
        renderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.WHITE);
        renderer.setXTitle("mins");
        renderer.setYTitle("Tweets");
        renderer.setShowAxes(true);  
        renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
        renderer.setBarSpacing(0.2);
        renderer.setBarWidth(15);
        renderer.setShowGrid(false);
        renderer.setYLabels(0);
        renderer.setXLabels(0); // sets the number of integer labels to appear

        int margin[]  =  renderer.getMargins();
        renderer.setMargins(new int[] { (int)convertDiptoPixel(margin[0]), (int)convertDiptoPixel(margin[1]), (int)convertDiptoPixel(margin[2]), (int)convertDiptoPixel(margin[3]) });
        renderer.setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00));
        renderer.setLabelsColor(Color.WHITE);
        renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(convertDiptoPixel(renderer.getAxisTitleTextSize()));


        renderer.setShowLegend(false);
        renderer.setLabelsTextSize(convertDiptoPixel(renderer.getLabelsTextSize()));
        renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(false);
        renderer.setPanEnabled(true, true); 
        renderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);

        renderer.setClickEnabled(true);
        renderer.setSelectableBuffer(10);
       }
    }




    private void getBarGraphDataset() {
        if(mBarGraph != null){
            CategorySeries positiveSeries = new CategorySeries("Positive");
            ArrayList<Sentiment> sentimentList = mBarGraph.getSentimentList();
            if(sentimentList != null && !sentimentList.isEmpty()){
                Sentiment sentiment = null;
                for(int i=0; i< sentimentList.size(); i++){
                      sentiment = sentimentList.get(i);
                      positiveSeries.add(sentiment.getTotalTweetCount());
                }
                mDataset.addSeries(positiveSeries.toXYSeries());
            }
        }
    }



  public XYMultipleSeriesRenderer getBarRenderer() {
       XYSeriesRenderer   seriesRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
       seriesRenderer.setColor(Color.parseColor("#5FB356"));
       seriesRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
       renderer.addSeriesRenderer(seriesRenderer);
       return renderer;
    }




private  float convertDiptoPixel(float pixel){
    return TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, pixel, mMetrics);
}


OnClickListener onBarClick = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        SeriesSelection seriesSelection = ((GraphicalView) barChartView).getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
        if (seriesSelection == null) {
          Toast.makeText(mContext, "No chart element was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
              .show();
        } else {

          double[] screenPoint = chart.toScreenPoint(new double[] {
                  seriesSelection.getXValue(),seriesSelection.getValue() },0);
          Toast toast =  Toast.makeText(
                mContext,
                  "Chart element in series index " + seriesSelection.getSeriesIndex()
                  + " data point index " + seriesSelection.getPointIndex() + " was clicked"
                  + " closest point value X=" + seriesSelection.getXValue() + ", Y=" + seriesSelection.getValue()
                  + " clicked point value X=" +  (int)screenPoint[0] + ", Y=" + (int)screenPoint[1], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

          toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, (int)screenPoint[0],(int)screenPoint[1]);
          toast.show();

        }
    }
};
```

}

Comment: If u have series then u can find ,what is problem?

Comment: If you don't mind can you please explain how to do that ? Which method we have to use ?

Comment: You should add ur code what r u doing .

Comment: Added code snippet in the question

Comment: You can add texts on bar but you can't add image .Achartengine does not provide such functionality as I know .You may have to change in source of library for this requirement .

Comment: okay, Can we able to get the top position of bar in the bar graph ? If we can , then thought to show a popup window in that coordinates. Do have any idea how to get the click on the bar properly ?

Comment: You can implement touch to graph and check whether it is touching the bar and then show popup

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54702/discussion-between-android-fryo-and-keshav).